# Two version of same libary with same package name in one application

Tags: java, package

I need to connect single app to two different application. First application is using protocol P in version 1 second is using same protocol in version 2. Libraries are incompatible so I have to use both in my app. Problem is that they are using same package e.g. com.company.P and architecture (class names, packages) are the same.

Is it possible to use both of them in same app?

Comment: Yes: use two ClassLoaders

Comment: @MauricePerry How? any example would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple example: you need a jar for your main application, in which you define an interface Service:

```
package multiverse;

public interface Service {
    public String getDescription();
}
```

And a Main class creates an instance of the service from the jars in two different directories:

```
package multiverse;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Main {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());
    private static final File DIR1
            = new File("../multiverse-v1/dist");
    private static final File DIR2
            = new File("../multiverse-v2/dist");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Service service1 = loadService(DIR1);
        Service service2 = loadService(DIR2);
        System.out.println(service1.getDescription());
        System.out.println(service2.getDescription());
    }

    private static Service loadService(File dir) {
        try {
            File[] jars = dir.listFiles((File file) -> file.isFile()
                    && file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".jar"));
            URL[] urls = new URL[jars.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < jars.length; ++i) {
                urls[i] = jars[i].toURI().toURL();
            }
            ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
            Class<? extends Service> clazz
                    = (Class<? extends Service>) cl.loadClass(
                            "multiverse.ServiceImpl");
            return clazz.newInstance();
        } catch (MalformedURLException | ClassNotFoundException
                | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            throw new RuntimeException(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have two implementations of the service, in two different jars, one in each of the directories used by the program above:

```
package multiverse;

public class ServiceImpl implements Service {
    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return "Service V1";
    }
}
```

and

```
package multiverse;

public class ServiceImpl implements Service {
    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return "Service V2";
    }    
}
```

Note that they must have access to the Service interface when they are compile. This interface can be in the same jar as the main program, or in a separate jar. The main program cannot access directly the classes of the jars used for each implementation: it must always go through an interface.

Comment: Unfortunately my case is that I do not have interface. I have two classes with same qualified name in two different jars.

Comment: @Trismegistos OK, write an interface

Comment: I can not because those libraries are not provide by me.

Comment: @Trismegistos they don't need to